How do I upload my C# ASP.NET project to Git Hub?
I'm currently trying to upload an ASP.NET website I've created to Github and I'm not having any luck doing this. Could I please get a step-by-step explanation on how this might be done?
The site was built in Visual Studio and has a connection to my SQL database (side note: if I can upload the site will my database still keep updating when user input is taken?).
Thank you in advance
I watched a Youtube video, but it was not informative at all, I'm trying to upload the website to Github

Note that Github page only host static website, which means you wont be able to connect to a database with Github page. You will still see the front-end though.
HOWEVER, there is a tricky way to host a ASP.NET Web form on Github page in this article. Similar problem has been asked here
Another solution is not using Github at all, use MS Azure instead: \
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/hosting
